# Не отображаются картинки на странице JSP

Tags: java, html

Добрый день, есть страничка `test.jsp`, в ней есть код html получающий картинку стандартным тегом:

```
    <img src="C:\Users\PopovVA\eclipse-workspace\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\img\icon_search.png"/>
```

Проблема в том, что если я использую любое другое изображение, то оно не отображается,

```
    <img src="C:\Users\PopovVA\eclipse-workspace\test\WebContent\WEB-INF\img\test.png"/>
```

Изображения одинаковые по размеру и по расширению (png). В корень приложения кидать пробовал, не помогает.
    Сервер TomCat 9.0 IDE Eclipse (на всякий)
        В Web.xml есть строчки для png

```
    <mime-mapping>
            <extension>png</extension>
            <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

[image: Вот test.png]

[image: Изображение которое выводится]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому вдруг поможет, проблема была в том что страничка не поддерживала цветовую гамму картинки, выход: Конвертировать цветовую гамму